# vbscript mapping printer in logon, error 800703F0

Tags: authentication, vbscript

My script to map a printer on Windows 7 is failing and shows an error `800703F0`, while the same script running on Windows XP works without a problem.
What's wrong with it?

```
Impresora01 = "\\mistral\Piso 2 Sucursal 958 Lexmark MX711"
ImpresoraDATACARD = "DATA"
Call Agregar_Impresora()
WScript.Quit 0

Sub Agregar_Impresora()
Dim WshNetwork
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection Impresora01
WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter Impresora01

For i=1 To WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections.Count -1 Step 2
if left(WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections(i),4) = impresoraDATACARD Then
WshNetwork.SetDefaultPrinter WshNetwork.EnumPrinterConnections(i)
End If
Next
Set WshNetwork=nothing
End Sub`
```

Comment: What operating system is `mistral`?

Comment: Mistral is Windows 2008 R2 server